# Apache POI sometime renders LocalDateTime as double

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I have this code snippet for exporting data into XLS:

```
final Cell newCell = dataRow.createCell(cellNo);
    
final CellStyle cellStyleDateDt = workbook.createCellStyle();
final CreationHelper creationHelperDt = workbook.getCreationHelper();
cellStyleDateDt.setDataFormat(creationHelperDt.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm"));
    
newCell.setCellValue(DateUtil.getExcelDate((LocalDateTime) cell.getValue()));
newCell.setCellStyle(cellStyleDateDt);
```

Sometime final XLS file is rendered like this - some `LocalDateTime` values are rendered as `double`.

[image]

I have Microsoft Excel for Mac, version 16.55.

**Q:** Is there a way how to render XLS as requested format `dd.mm.yyyy HH:mm`?

Comment: As no complete example is given only guessing is possible. But it exactly looks like you are creating a cell style for each cell and so exceeds the limit of possible cell style count. Then after that cells only have numeric (date) cell values without style. Do creating the cell style only once on workbook level and then set that one cell style to all date cells.

Answer (score 3):

POI has a setCellValue(LocalDateTime) on the Cell interface (inherited by HSSFCell for xls support) -- https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.time.LocalDateTime-

You may need to upgrade POI to get this.

Comment: The cell style is also needed - it is worth double checking that you are putting the style on all the cells that need it. Try to reuse the same cell style instance on as many date cells as possible because there is a limit on the number of styles you can add (an Excel limit).